# Is it true that a port can be closed?

Tags: networking, serial-port, port, communication

I heard someone saying that a "port should be opened" , said a person inside a closed room in our company. So I wonder that it is possible to close a port ! So is it true that a port can be closed and/or opened ? If so how to close it , and how to open it ?

Comment: Do not confuse a serial port with a network port. The later can be closed, the former not.

Comment: @DarkDust: Or rather, a TCP/IP port is closed (and network stack responds on it with RST) unless there is a process bound to it, thus opening it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on you operating system, the firewall can be configured to block traffic on selected ports.

For example, on Windows 7, you can do this by opening the firewall advanced settings and creating a new rule for incoming/outgoing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ports he is talking about is operating system related ports but not hardware related. Operating systems ports lie unused until a certain number, in which OS uses lot of ports for its internal functions. But sometime when a user wants to run a software like server and access it, he has to do it through one of the port. However hardware ports also can be thought as opened and closed, unless you connect it with a cable. Be it a mouse or anything, otherwise ports are opened, if cable is unused.